# Filling search form with mechanize

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I'm trying to make a search on a website using [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) (first experience with this lib and i almost don't know html and browsing mechanics).

It works okay for logging in a site, but than i fail to fill a search forms on next page.
For logging in i use:

```
    from mechanize import Browser
    br = Browser()
    br.open(top_url)
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br["login"] = username
    br["password"] = password
    br.submit()
```

Then i'd used loop on forms to see names of the form fields:

```
>>> for i in br.forms():
...     print i
...     break
...
```

That gave me this:

```
<naurp_form POST https://sd.priocom.com/fx/$sd/servlet.ru.naumen.sd.search.SearcherServlet multipart/form-data
  <TextControl(sdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType=)>
  <SubmitControl(dosearchsdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType=>) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(hidden_dosearchsdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType=) (readonly)>
  <TextControl(sdsearch_ServiceCallDescriptionSearchType=)>
  <SubmitControl(dosearchsdsearch_ServiceCallDescriptionSearchType=>) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(hidden_dosearchsdsearch_ServiceCallDescriptionSearchType=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(searchType__exists=1) (readonly)>
  <SelectControl(searchType=[ClientTitleSearchType, *ClientTitleSearchType, CrmLiteJuridicalClientContactPersonSearchType, CrmLiteByPhoneSearchType, ServiceTitleSearchType, ContractTitleSearchType, CrmLiteNaturalClientSearchType, CrmLiteJuridicalClientSearchType, SDTaskIdSearchType, SDTaskDescriptionSearchType, SDTaskIdSearchType, ServiceCallIdSearchType, ServiceCallCommentSearchType, CoreEmployeeSearchType, CoreOUSearchType, CoreEmployeeSearchType, CoreClientSearchType, CoreContractTitleSearchType, CoreServiceSearchType, KBaseSearchType, CMDBObjectTitleSearchType, CMDBObjectInvNumberSearchType])>
  <TextControl(searchString=)>
  <SubmitControl(doSearch=>) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(hidden_doSearch=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(searchUUID=) (readonly)>
  <CheckboxControl(searchInResult=[on])>
  <HiddenControl(searchInResult__exists=1) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(backURL=/fx/sd/ru.naumen.sd.published_jsp?uuid=coreboqme50d80000il15pbh3tiac13s) (readonly)>
  <SubmitControl(doClear=╨Ю╤З╨╕╤Б╤В╨╕╤В╤М ╤А╨╡╨╖╤Г╨╗╤М╤В╨░╤В╤Л) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(hidden_doClear=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(__form_id=searchTab.searchForm) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(first_load=true) (readonly)>>
```

Total number of forms = 3 (0,1,2) what exactly matches web site.
I'm interested in first form, `"sdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType"`.
On actual website it looks like a field and a button ">>", obviously `dosearchsdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType`

So i'm trying this:

```
br.select_form(nr = 0)
br['sdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType'] = '2770' 
#also tried br.form['sdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType'] = '2770'
response = br.submit("dosearchsdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType")
tt_page = br.response().read()
```

**UPD**:
also tried with `.click()` method

```
response = br.click(type = 'submit',name = "dosearchsdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType")
tt_page = br.response().read()
```

But in `tt_page` i still receive first search page (page where i'm trying to fill search form).

Any tips appreciated.

PS: Code of search form on website i need (I DON'T KNOW WHAT IT MEANS. I can guess but can't be sure my guess is true):

```
<!--formbutton.jsp-->
<tr id="sdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType_outer" >
    <th style="width:25%;">
        TT number
    </th>
    <td  align="left"
        style="width:100%;vertical-align:middle;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="border:0px">
        <input type="text"
               id="sdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType"
               name="sdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType"
               size="30"
               value=""
               maxlength="254"               
               style="" 
        />
        </td><td style="border:0px">
<span id="dosearchsdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType_outer"
    name="dosearchsdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType_outer"
    ><input
        onclick="
                mark_as_pressed(window.event, this);
                "
        style="margin:1px;"    
    type="submit"
    id="dosearchsdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType"
    name="dosearchsdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType"
    value="&#062;"
/></span>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_dosearchsdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType" name="hidden_dosearchsdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType"></td></tr></table></td>
</tr>
```

PPS:
[This post was helpfull](http://stockrt.github.com/p/handling-html-forms-with-python-mechanize-and-BeautifulSoup/) and also some of posts on this site. But none gave me any tip why in my case it isn't working.

Still can't find a way to fill that form and go to next page.

Comment: Lucky me, that site has pages. So i just used "follow_link" to run through them and look for link i need.

Answer (score 0):

```
br.select_form(nr = 0)
br['sdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType'] = '2770' 
br.submit()
```

This should work for submitting a form to search!

Answer (score 0):

What Robin said should work, except for my forms I have to use

```
br['sdsearch_ServiceCallIdSearchType'] = ['2770']
```

Otherwise we're pretty much the same.